# Apache Storm Services Stopping

Tags: java, apache, apache-storm

I am installing storm onto an environment at work, but currently only the Nimbus service is running. When I start Supervisor/Ui they run for about 30 seconds/a minute before entering a stopped state.

Zookeeper is also running normally.

I thought it could be do to an error in one of the wrapper.conf files during installation, but I've checked thoroughly and the paths are all correct as far as I can tell. Looking in service logs for supervisor/ui I can see this;

*INFO|3528/0|Service Storm-Supervisor|19-01-08 14:49:11|Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect*

*INFO|6668/0|Service Storm-UI|19-01-08 14:49:22|Caused by: java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect*

Which I believe is causing the service to stop. Also at the start of the log these messages are present;

WARNING|wrapper|Service Storm-Supervisor|19-01-08 14:49:04|YAJSW: yajsw-stable-11.11

WARNING|wrapper|Service Storm-Supervisor|19-01-08 14:49:04|OS   : Windows Server 2012 R2/6.3/amd64

WARNING|wrapper|Service Storm-Supervisor|19-01-08 14:49:04|JVM  : Oracle Corporation/1.8.0_171/C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171/64

WARNING|wrapper|Service Storm-Supervisor|19-01-08 14:49:05|error binding port for system tray icon, please check configuration

Any help would be appreciated, this is my first ever storm installation attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who has a similar issue, I needed to also install the relevant JDK ontop of JRE and point to the JDK\tools.jar in the genconfig section of each wrapper.config.